# The force Interaction between two charge spherical surfaces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electrostatics, electric-fields

I have to solve the following problem:
Two spherical surfaces with radii $\:R_1\:$ and $\:R_2\:$ and electric charges $\:Q_1\:$ and $\:Q_2\:$ respectively are placed in such a way that the distance between their centers is $\:d$, where $\:0\le d \le R_1 + R_2\:$. Find the force of interaction between these spheres.

I've calculated the electric field of the spheres, and by superposition of the electric field in the overlap region I've found the resultant electric field of the overlap as a function of the vector $\:\mathbf d\:$ that unite the centers.

Finally, for the expression of the force, I've found something similar to the coulomb law. The point is, I don't really know if the result is accurate, doesn't look solid for me.

Comment: The spheres overlap?  Is this a typo: $0 \leq d \leq R_1 + R_2$ ?

Comment: Since you talk about spheres (and not balls) I suppose that the electric charge $\:Q_k\:$ is uniformly distributed on the spherical surface $\:R_k\:$ (uniform surface density $\:\sigma_k\:$) and not in the volume of the ball (uniform volume density $\:\rho_k\:$).

Comment: You must show your results. But even doing this your question will be closed as "check- my-work".

Comment: @Frobenius If the material is non-conducting, and the charge is somehow forced to be fixed and uniform, then Gauss law shows that it is irrelevant whether it is a uniform surface density on a sphere or a uniform volume density in a ball. Provided of course that Pat is right about the typo (the spheres do not overlap), the interaction is the same as if the whole charge of each spheres or balls were concentrated at its center. In, conversely, the sphere or balls are conductors, then the charge is on the surface, but not uniform, as each surface must be an equipotential. Very hard problem !

Comment: @Alfred : I agree with you in case of not overlap.